# Nothing happens when I right-click the taskbar

Tags: taskbar, context-menu, right-click

I don't get the context menu for the taskbar (or any kind of reaction at all) when I right-click an empty portion of the taskbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a text file with the following contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoTrayContextMenu"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoTrayContextMenu"=-
```

Then rename it to `whatever.reg`

Then double click on it. You may have to reboot for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I finally got around to this (don't ask), and it solved the problem. Thanks very much! Now I wonder what originally changed to disable the taskbar context menu and what was responsible for changing it.

Answer (score -1):

Open the command prompt as administrator. Then run the

```
sfc /scannow
```

command. Wait for the execution of the command, and then restart your PC.